# SSRS Report data looks different on reporting server vs local preview

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have created an SSRS Report which loads all the columns as expected in my local preview when viewed in Visual Studio. But after deploying to Report Server, it shows 0 in columns that have numeric data. These columns are of Varchar, Big Int data types. Columns that have DateTime, string type show correct data.

I tried below without any success.
Redeploying the report multiple times.
Removing and re-adding columns.
Removing *.data* files every time I change something.

My SSRS Version is 15.0.19049.0. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this weird issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Try removing the server version of the report and then re-deploying. Also make sure that the datasource is pointing to the same server in both the local and deployed versions, by default, datasources are not overwritten. If that fails run a trace on the server and see what is actually being executed on the server, copy and paste the trace sql into your sql editor and test the output matches your expectations. Finally, in your local report, try refrshing the fields in your dataset.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, How can I remove the server version? I'm only able to change the target Report server version or detect. It looks like a mandatory field that needs to be selected in properties. Changing it to 2016 or later (my reporting server is 2016) didn't work as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant move the report from the server via the web portal. At least you will know that if the report re-appears it is what you have just deployed.

Comment: Ahh ok, got it. Actually, from the report updated date, I see it's being deployed to the server correctly but somehow the data is still showing up 0 in those columns. Such a weird issue, haven't seen any questions posted here on such issues. Thank you for the suggestions though.

Comment: You should still remove and redeploy though.  Some report settings are not overwritten during the deploy (such as default parameter values) so it's worth just deleting it to be sure. Next up would be running a server trace on the t-sql actually being executed